# Python: Getting actual value of object changed in Process

Tags: python, python-2.7, process

I'm trying to understand how Process class from the multiprocessing package works.
For this, I wrote a little example, where an object with certain value is created and then that value is changed in subprocess:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "foo"

    def run(self):
        p = Process(target=self.change_value)
        p.start()
        p.join()

    def change_value(self):
        self.value = "bar"
        print "inside: " + self.value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.run()
    print "outside: " + foo.value
```

But this code gives me the following result:

```
>> inside: bar
>> outside: foo
```

Can someone explain me why it prints old property value ("foo") from the outside of a process despite the fact that second print is executed later?
And how to get actual value of that property ("bar") from the outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `multiprocessing.Process` spawns a completely new, seperate instance of the python-environment in a new process. You will notice that in the taskmanager a new `python.exe` process will appear as you start the `Process`. It does - if you don't use the special objects such as `Pipe` and `Queue` - not share memory with the process it has been started from.

#### A little more about the internal work that is done:

- You call `p.start()`. This will `pickle` the `Process` object p and spawn a new instance of the python interpreter with an own global state, etc... It does not share memory with the original process. Instead the pickled `p` is unpickled in the new process and work is done there.
- `print "inside: " + self.value`: This is called by the newly spawned process thus the change done is reflected here
- `print "outside: " + foo.value`: This is called in the original process that does have no idea about the memory of the spawned process and does not have access to it. Thus the `foo` is not changed in the process

#### What I guess you intended to use

Most likely the class you search for is `threading.Thread`. It offers the same interface as `Process` but it shares the global state and the python environment with the `Thread` it is started from. Any changes to objects in a spawned `Thread` can be read from outside.

Comment: Thank you! This is really the explanation I was looking for. Now I know how to work with it and how to get data from other process (using Queue).